# In Emacs' org-mode, any way to hide the subtree with timestamp not set to today?

Tags: emacs, timestamps, org-mode

I just started to learn [org-mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Org-Mode.html#Org-Mode) (and *Emacs*) and I plan to use it as a *calendar/timetable/todo-list* hybrid. Is it possible to hide entries with timestamp not set to today? If so, how?

For example, say if today is 2014-09-18:

```
* Lunch

* TODO Call boss
  <2014-09-18 Thu 13:30pm>

   ** Report :: Nothing happened

* TODO Call Bob                             ; This entry will not be shown
  <2014-09-19 Fri 13:30pm>                  ; This entry will not be shown
                                            ; This entry will not be shown
   ** Discuss :: Project Alice              ; This entry will not be shown
   ** Discuss :: Upgrading to CentOS 5      ; This entry will not be shown

* TODO Fetch Claire from school
```

Incidentally, are there any more efficient way to deal with calendar/timetable/todo-lists in org-mode?